# Laravel 7 Como puedo obtener el id del ultimo usuario que registre

Tags: php, laravel

Quiero obtener el valor del ultimo registro realizado, para poder insertarlo en otra tabla. Revise algunas soluciones pero obtengo siempre un resultado null

```
$idEquipo = $request['equipo'];
    $nombre = $request['nombre'];
    $apellido = $request['apellido'];
    $manejo = $request['manejo'];
    $femad = $request['femad'];
    $caducidad = $request['caducidad'];
    $user =  auth()->user()->email;
    $fechahoy = date('Y-m-d H:i:s');
    $participante = new Participantes();
    $participante->idEquipo = $idEquipo;
    $participante->nombre = $nombre;
    $participante->apellido = $apellido;
    $participante->licenciaManejo = $manejo;
    $participante->licenciaFEMAD = $femad;
    $participante->usuarioRegistro = $user;
    $participante->caducidadLicencia = $caducidad;
    $participante->created_at = $fechahoy;
    $participante->save();
    $lastId = $participante->idParticipante;
```

Answer (score 0):

de donde quieres llamar el id? de la base de datos o estas guardando las dos tablas en el mismo controlador?
si por ejemplo nesesistas obtener al id del particpante que estas guardando seria asi.

`$id = $participante->id;`  y lo podrias usar en tu siguiente insert o consulta

Comment: Quiero llamar el id del registro que se acaba de hacer, para despues insertarlo en otra tabla. Si estoy guardantdo las dos en el mismo controlador

Comment: el id no lo esperas del request , lo obtienes de la coleccion que acabas de crear.  donde lo nesesites colocas la coleccion id , $coleccion->id;

Comment: valida primero si realmente estas guardando $participante, porque si despues del save() no obtenes el id , no funciono el insert

Answer (score -1):

Esta fue mi solucion

```
    $id = DB::table('users')->insertGetId(
    ['email' => 'john@example.com', 'votes' => 0]
);
```

El código realiza una insercion en la tabla 'Users' insertando un nuevo campo con los registros email y votes. La función "insertGetId()" devuelve el ID generado automáticamente para el nuevo registro insertado.

Comment: Pulsa en [edit] y describe cómo este código responde a tu pregunta, para que sea de utilidad no solo para ti, sino para otros que también lleguen a tener el mismo problema. Lee [answer].